# WPF toolkit how to properly add series

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, wpftoolkit

I'm trying to make work the following code:

**XAML:**

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <charts:Chart x:Name="chart1"/>
</Grid>
```

I am using

```
xmlns:charts="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit
```

**CODE**

```
using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;
public MainWindow()
{
            InitializeComponent();
        PointCollection pc = new PointCollection();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            pc.Add(new System.Windows.Point { X = i, Y = i * 2 });
        }

        LineSeries series1 = new LineSeries();
        series1.DependentValuePath = "Y";
        series1.IndependentValuePath = "X";
        series1.ItemsSource = pc;
        chart1.Series.Add(series1);
}
```

But I'm getting *Unsupported exception error*:

```
Exception thrown: 'System.NotSupportedException' in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: Cannot convert the value in attribute 'Property' to object of type 'System.Windows.DependencyProperty'.
```

The error comes along with the 'No source available' screen, 
I am using Visual Studio 2015.

I've read that chart.series is not a dependency property, so my questions is what is the proper way of assigning values to series ?

Comment: Please be more specific... the following worked for me: `xmlns:charts="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"` (do you use a different chart?) and executing your code in main window constructor or loaded event. So please make sure to include all information that is needed to reproduce your error.

Comment: As commented, I can't reproduce your issue. Please explain exactly when you get the exception... does your code even execute by then or does it happen before/during `InitializeComponent`?

Comment: Thank you for replying. The error shows pop up at this line: `chart1.Series.Add(series1);` I think it has to do with having too many CLR Exceptions being caught in my project, when I start default project I don't get this error but when I choose all CLR exception types - it shows

Comment: I hope you understand I can't help you when the source of the problem is *a lot of CLR Exceptions that are not part of the question*. I suggest you start with the first CLR exception and try to solve it.

Comment: Can you just confirm if this code represents the right method of adding values to the chart?

Comment: Oops, the whole error thing got me off tracks... gonna write an answer.

Answer (score 0):

> I've read that chart.series is not a dependency property, so my questions is what is the proper way of assigning values to series ?

You should specify your series type statically in XAML and bind the points collection as its `ItemsSource`:

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <charts:Chart x:Name="chart1">
        <charts:Chart.Series>
            <charts:LineSeries IndependentValuePath="X" DependentValuePath="Y" ItemsSource="{Binding points}"/>
        </charts:Chart.Series>
    </charts:Chart>
</Grid>
```

Initialization code:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    PointCollection pc = new PointCollection();

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        pc.Add(new System.Windows.Point { X = i, Y = i * 2 });
    }

    // in some appropriate datacontext, set some object that contains your points collection for the binding
    chart1.DataContext = new { points = pc };
}
```

Note: this doesn't explain the errors that where mentioned in the question, it's just a way to define the chart with better View-ViewModel separation than the question approach. The question code for itself isn't enough to reproduce the error.

Comment: Ok, I can reproduce it. I'm using System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit ver 4.0.0.0 from NuGet. If you go to Debug -> Windows -> Exception Settings and tick all CLR Exceptions it should give you the same error I have

Comment: @SamHicks What about the nuget packages `WPFToolkit.DataVisualization` (3.5.50211.1) and `WPF Toolkit` (3.5.50211.1)? The `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit` (4.0.0.0) doesn't even have a `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization` namespace as far as I can tell. And no, I'm really not getting the exception, so there is nothing to be catched.

Comment: @SamHicks Just to be clear: you created a fresh WPF project, added the nuget package, configured the break on exception, created the window with __only__ the grid/chart as mentioned here and used only the initialization code that's displayed here and you still got the exception? If so, you may want to add everything like VS Version (you mentioned that), .Net Version etc.

Comment: `Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.25431.01 Update 3`
`Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.02046`  Yes I tried a fresh project, based on the info I posted here. On more thing, the option: Options->Debugging->General ->Enable just my code - must be unticked in order to get this error

Comment: @SamHicks ok, I confirmed the error with disabled *"Enable just my code"* settings. Now I can at least take a closer look, I don't know if I can figure out the reason.